# how to make spinner shows value from what it selected for the second time

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

i'm trying to make my spinner shows value depends on what it selected before. but **it for the second time** because i did it in the first time it shows depend on selected item before but it's not working when i try it in the second time depends on what it selected from the first time selected before.

this is my code

```
gedungSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                LantaiSpinnerRektorat();
                lantaiSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i) {
                            case 0 : RuanganLantai1Rekto();
                            case 1 : RuanganLantai2Rekto();
                            case 2 : RuanganLantai3Rekto();
                            case 3 : RuanganLantai4Rekto();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    }
                });
            } else if (position == 1) {
                LantaiSpinnerGL();
                lantaiSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i){
                            case 0 : RuanganLantai1GL();
                            case 1 : RuanganLantai2GL();
                            case 2 : RuanganLantai3GL();
                            case 3 : RuanganLantai4GL();
                            case 4 : RuanganLantai5GL();
                            case 5 : RuanganLantai6GL();
                            case 6 : RuanganLantai7GL();
                            case 7 : RuanganLantai8GL();
                            case 8 : RuanganLantai9GL();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

please help me to make it work. it's not a duplicate question because i want to make the spinner depends on item selected for the second time item selected before. the code i have tried in swich case statement.

it not shows any error

Answer (score 0):

It is not a right to put a listener for item1 inside a listener for item2, so separate the 2 listeners from each other. create a variable gedungSelectedItemPosition which will only hold 0 or 1 based on the first spinner's selection. Then OnItemSelectedListener of the second spinner, check whether gedungSelectedItemPosition is 0 or 1 before processing your selection. Check my code below:

```
int gedungSelectedItemPosition = -1; //initializing it with a value not 0 or 1

gedungSpn = findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id); 
lantaiSpn = findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id); 

gedungSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    gedungSelectedItemPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});



lantaiSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (gedungSelectedItemPosition == 0) {
        LantaiSpinnerRektorat();
        switch (i) {
        case 0 : RuanganLantai1Rekto();
        case 1 : RuanganLantai2Rekto();
        case 2 : RuanganLantai3Rekto();
        case 3 : RuanganLantai4Rekto();
        }
        }
        else if(gedungSelectedItemPosition == 1){
        LantaiSpinnerGL();
        switch (i){
        case 0 : RuanganLantai1GL();
        case 1 : RuanganLantai2GL();
        case 2 : RuanganLantai3GL();
        case 3 : RuanganLantai4GL();
        case 4 : RuanganLantai5GL();
        case 5 : RuanganLantai6GL();
        case 6 : RuanganLantai7GL();
        case 7 : RuanganLantai8GL();
        case 8 : RuanganLantai9GL();
        }
        }
        }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
        });
```

Comment: i set `int gedungSelectedItemPosition = -1;` to global variable but it not working. it says  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference`

Comment: i'm sorry it works when i change swich case to if else in my old code. thanks for try to help

Comment: This means your Spinners are not initialized. gedungSpn = findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id); lantaiSpn = findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id); I have edited my answer above